# Chromium Browser Branding

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I've been struggling all day trying to build Chromium and understand how branding works, but no luck with the later one.

The question is: how can I change the application name, logo and default search engine in the source files of Chromium ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it:

On Chromium dev by James Atkinson

[How to change Chromium app name and logo?](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-dev/change%2420logo/chromium-dev/hVv04bSV7sM/J2m23-kkYYwJ)

"What is the right place to change Chromium application name, program 
title, .exe file name, and logo image. I guess there is place in 
source code for windows, where it could be changed centralized for 
whole project?"

Comment: this seems to be obsolete and does not having too much information. Here is new question about Chromium branding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514975/proper-chromium-browser-branding

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a centralized place to change all at once. I'll advise you to go through .grd files search for .ico file an look at resources folder under chrome/browser/ it will give you a good start.
There are actually more places needs to be changed and I didn't found any doc describing the process.

There are some branding constants which are in the source itself,  Like the folder name under app data which is embedded inside the code itself.