# Proper chromium browser branding?

Tags: java, google-chrome, fork, chromium, branding

I'm working on Chromium fork. How can i replace Chromium resources and app package?

1. Resources

I've found that one day `android_branding_res_dirs` gn argument was [introduced](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/60e61e8a7f98c447baadb317ad56d49c755e0071%5E%21/#F0):

```
@@ -43,10 +43,10 @@

 # GYP: //chrome/chrome.gyp:chrome_java (resources part)
 android_resources("chrome_java_resources") {
-  resource_dirs = [
-    "java/res",
-    "java/res_default",
-  ]
+  if (!defined(android_branding_res_dirs)) {
+    android_branding_res_dirs = [ "//chrome/android/java/res_chromium" ]
+  }
+  resource_dirs = [ "java/res" ] + android_branding_res_dirs
   deps = [
     ":chrome_locale_paks",
     ":chrome_strings_grd",
```

but then [broken](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/1db26ac88b5195d575f23fe6120ec1f643950300%5E%21/#F2):

```
@@ -43,10 +43,10 @@

 # GYP: //chrome/chrome.gyp:chrome_java (resources part)
 android_resources("chrome_java_resources") {
-  if (!defined(android_branding_res_dirs)) {
-    android_branding_res_dirs = [ "//chrome/android/java/res_chromium" ]
-  }
-  resource_dirs = [ "java/res" ] + android_branding_res_dirs
+  resource_dirs = [
+    "java/res",
+    "//chrome/android/java/res_chromium",
+  ]
   deps = [
     ":chrome_locale_paks",
     ":chrome_strings_grd",
```

So is adding `res_myfork` directory and replacing `res_chromium` with `res_myfork` in `chrome/android/BUILD.gn` **proper** way to add fork resources now?

2. App package

I've found `manifest_package` in `chrome/android/BUILD.gn`:

```
manifest_package = "org.chromium.chrome"
```

Also i can see `custom_package = "org.chromium.chrome"`:

```
android_resources("chrome_java_resources") {
  resource_dirs = [
    "java/res",
    "//chrome/android/java/res_chromium", // replaced to `res_myfork`
  ]
  ...

  custom_package = "org.chromium.chrome" // replaced to `org.company.myfork` by me
}
```

When building i'm getting errors:

Since i can see in most java classes package resource namespace is hardcoded (eg. `/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/ntp/cards/ActionItem.java`):

```
import org.chromium.chrome.R;
```

What is **proper** way to reference resources?
Should i just replace such lines to my package resources namespace?
Is there any python script to do it automatically while building?

Should i replace `custom_package` or leave it as-is?

UPDATE 1.

I've found word "Chrome" to be hardcoded in most strings like in `./chrome/android/java/strings/android_chrome_strings.grd`:

```
  <!-- Sign-in preference -->
  <message name="IDS_SIGN_IN_TO_CHROME" desc="Title for the button to sign in to Chrome using one's Google account. [CHAR-LIMIT=27]">
    Sign in to Chrome
  </message>
```

Is there any way to adjust it (script) or should i just change it? I'd like to avoid conflicts while merging in the future so i'm looking for proper way (or lest painless way) to do it.

UPDATE 2.

I can see how Brave browser did it:
https://github.com/brave/browser-android-tabs/commit/b3fa10a7b10379c8ce5cdbeb68e3c52b580292da

https://github.com/brave/browser-android-tabs/commit/956bd321871844f72d98b9666434e5aceac7da81

is it really good way?

Comment: did you find any solution to change the package name and logo?

Comment: Nope. Just replace hardcoded package name to argument (in .gn file) with default value = hardcoded one

Comment: pls can you show with any piece of code and any screenshot for your above comment. Actually, I am new in chromium development.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

In [`src/chrome/android/BUILD.gn`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/android/BUILD.gn?rcl=c747570d3ccffc199c837ee42be43b40790fb82e&l=38)

```
 import('package.gni')
 ...
 chrome_public_manifest_package = manifest_package
 chrome_public_test_manifest_package = test_manifest_package
```

Create a `package.gni` file:

```
declare_args() {
    manifest_package = "org.chromium.chrome"
    test_manifest_package = "${manifest.package}.tests"
}
```

Now feel free to override it when `gn gen .. manifest_package="com.company.fork"`

PS. BTW try to override `chrome_public_manifest_package` directly first without that changes.

Comment: this worked for me, now I am able to change the package name

Comment: where are you running `gn gen .. manifest_package=""` from?